# What is the best regularity of a rough path?

Tags: integration, analysis, stochastic-differential-equations, total-variation, rough-path-theory

Assume we have a one dimensional rough path $\mathbf{X} = (X, \mathbb{X})$ with finite $p$-variation, with $p \in (1,2]$. Assuming that $Y$ is controlled in the sense of Gubinelli with respect to the path $X$. Then, what is the $p$-variation of the rough path integral
$$F(x) = \int_0^x Y \ d\mathbf{X}$$
By known estimates (see chapter IV of introduction to rough path by Hairer and Fritz),

$$
 |F(t) - F(s)| \le Y_s X_{s,t} + Y_s'\mathbb{X}_{s,t} + C|t-s|^{3/p}$$
for some constant $C$ depending on the $p$ and $p/2$ variation of the path and gubinelli's derivative/residue.

Hence, it seems that it's just of finite $p$-variation. But shouldn't it gain more regularity as we are considering the integral, i.e. getting to $p/2$ finite variation?

Comment: which estimate are you referring to from Hairer-Friz? In thm 4.10, I see $3\alpha$ exponent.

Comment: in terms of the p-variation. This is indeed just the best possible as you can see from the definition of the Gubinelli-derivative in terms of Xs,t. It is no different than with Ito integrals inheriting the regularity of Brownian motion.

Comment: This already happens for Young integrals. The integration map goes from $C^\alpha\times C^\beta$ to $C^\beta$, as long as $\alpha+\beta>1$. This follows from Young's inequality, of which Thm. 4.10. in FH is an extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The estimate I see in 4.10 thm in Hairer-Friz i s a bit better

$$|\int_{s}^{t}Y_{r}dX_{r}-Y_s X_{s,t} + Y_s'\mathbb{X}_{s,t}|\leq  C|t-s|^{3\alpha}.$$

But yes the best possible is indeed p-variation because after all the Gubinelli derivative is defined as

$$\int_{s}^{t}Y_{r}dX_{r}=\lim_{|P|\to 0}\sum_{s,t\in P}Y_s X_{s,t} + Y_{s}' \mathbb{X}_{s,t}$$

and so we have to deal with the restricted regularity of $X_{s,t}$ at the very least. This situation is similar to that of Ito integrals, where at best we have $(\frac{1}{2})^{-}-$Hölder regularity.